# Securely accessing SMB shares over Internet

Tags: networking, site-to-site-vpn

I'm looking for some advice about securely offering CIFS shares over the Internet. The file server will be hosted on a cloud service (e.g. DigitalOcean). There will be up to 100 remote devices that need to access the share, although they wouldn't be transferring more than about 30MB on each connection. These devices would connect daily but not necessarily at the same time.

The remote devices are connected to the Internet via an M2M router with 4G mobile access.

What is the most efficient and secure way to allow access from the remote devices to the share? My thoughts are to use a site-to-site VPN?

---

One issue I failed to mention when I originally posted this, is that all the remote sites are on the same subnet (192.168.1.0/24). Is it easier to configure them as a remote user VPN rather than doing site-to-site VPNs?

---

So I've set up a site-to-site VPN (StrongSwan) which works nicely. The issue I have now is that the SMB server is on DigitalOcean, meaning that the server only has a public IP. The remote devices **will only** allow an IP address for the server (i.e. no FQDN). At the moment, I can set the IP address to the IP of the DigitalOcean server. I'm just thinking long term if I need to change that server for whatever reason, or that IP is changed, I can't go around to 100 devices and change the IP setting for the file server.

What is my best option for this? The VPN server and file server are the same.

Comment: I would go for the site-to-site vpn. We serve our nas remotely via vpn without problems

Comment: How many users connect simultaneously? Just wondering whether I'll start to notice performance issues?

Comment: Not that many, just around 20 because they are tipically "roadwarriors" that need to access to local documents. If it's a 30mb for connection, and perhaps not all togheters, should not be a problem.

Comment: A VPN is fine. You would have problems if the remote sites needed to talk to _each other_ (in that case, renumber everyone and/or deploy IPv6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Site-to-site.** If the remote devices were all in the same location or at least in a few fixed locations, site-to-site VPN would be ideal in order to prevent every device having it's own VPN client and authentication for it. In this case it seems that all the devices are in different remote locations. You could either make them connect directly to the cloud, or via your on-premises network.

As all the internal networks on your M2M 4G router are the same `192.168.1.0/24`, your VPN can't establish routes directly between all the networks, but you need a NAT. I guess connections between the clients wouldn't be needed, just between each client and the server.

**Security.** If the goal of this arrangement is to have the data off-site or the scalability the cloud can offer, I would use a cloud solution that only allows connections within private cloud network, not directly over the internet.

**Efficiency**. Using a VPN doesn't usually cause overhead in network utilization. Quite the opposite: a VPN can be configured to compress the connection even when it's not compressed in the original file sharing solution. Anyway, a cloud solution can well handle your 30MB transfers from 100 devices, a couple of time a day; and a 4G connection can handle each as they are distributed. Your requirements are comparably low.

**Usability.** Is there a built-in capability on your M2M routers to establish the VPN connection? Especially for BYOD devices this would be the easiest way for users, at a cost of security that a password authenticated software VPN client would offer.